# arduino DC motor direction change

Tags: arduino, relay, dc-motor

Hey Guys i have been following this [tutorial](http://www.instructables.com/id/Super-Easy-Reversible-Motor-Control-for-Arduino-/?ALLSTEPS) on dc motor direction control the only change i have made is using this relay [Relay Link](http://www.futureelectronics.com/en/technologies/electromechanical/relays/signal-relays/Pages/2605020-HFD2-012-M(257).aspx?IM=0) instead of one mentioned in the tutorial. How do I proceed further.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the tutorial is pretty comprehensive.  The only difference is that the pinout of your relay is different.  The pin order of your relay is:

Coil

Common

Normally Closed

Normally Open

In other words, the "Common" and "Normally Closed" rows are swapped.  You'll have to modify your wiring to compensate.

Comment: Sure will try it out and let you know thanks for the help :)